# Lebesgue measure of closure of a set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\{X_t \mid t\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be an iid sequence of normal random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Define $A(\omega) = \{X_t(\omega) \mid t\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$ and let $\overline{A(\omega)}$ be its closure. Let $\ell$ be Lebesgue measure. I am interested in the number
$$
P(\{\omega \mid \ell(\overline{A(\omega)}) = 0\}).
$$
Since $A(\omega)$ is a countable set for any $\omega$ we have $\ell(A(\omega)) = 0$. However, for some $\omega$ we could have for example $A(\omega)$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, so that $\ell(\overline{A(\omega)}) = 1$. In fact, I believe there are uncountably many $\omega$ for which  $\ell(\overline{A(\omega)}) > 0$.

Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem? Any references to texts that might help would be great too. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Some of your assumptions are not clear to me: You assume that $X_t$ are measurable functions, most likely to $\mathbb{R}$ as you later assume that there is the Lebesgue measure on their codomain. Then you say they are "normal", which is not clear to me. Do you assume that the induced probability is Gaussian and iid? You will also have a problem with the conditional probability you are asking for, as the "number" you are looking for is most likely a probability distribution that may not be well defined.

Comment: Let me try to be more clear. I edited the wanted probabilty, so it is the measure of a certain subset of $\Omega$. I assume the $X_t$ to be measurable functions to the real line with induced Gaussian probability and being iid.

Comment: Ok, now I see! So you are not interested in conditional probabilities, but your $\mid$ simply denotes "such that". I believe that the arbitraryness of the probability space will not allow you any conclusion. I will try to construct some examples for different results of your probability.

Comment: Exactly. Thank you very much. Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Then, for
each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the event $A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}:=\left\{ \left|X_{k}-q\right|<\frac{1}{n}\right\} $
has the probability $\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(1\right)}\right)>0$
which is independent of $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since the $\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}\right)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$
form a family of independent events, the Borel Cantelli lemma implies
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}\right)=1,\text{ i.e. }\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{c}\right)=0
$$
for the event
$$
A_{q,n}:=\left\{ A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}\text{ infinitely often}\right\} .
$$
Thus, the event
$$
A:=\bigcup_{\substack{q\in\mathbb{Q}\\
n\in\mathbb{N}
}
}A_{q,n}^{c}
$$
has probability zero.

We conclude that almost surely, the event $A^{c}=\bigcap_{q\in\mathbb{Q},n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{q,n}$
occurs, which means that for fixed $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
we have $\left|X_{k}-q\right|<\frac{1}{n}$ for infinitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
This implies that $q$ is an accomulation point of the sequence $\left(X_{k}\right)_{k}$.
Since this holds for arbitrary $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and since the set
of accumulations points of a sequence is closed, we get
$$
\overline{A\left(\omega\right)}=\mathbb{R}\text{ almost surely}.
$$
In particular,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{ \omega\,\mid\,\ell\left(\overline{A\left(\omega\right)}\right) = 0\right\} \right)=0.
$$

Finally, note that we did not really use that each $X_k$ is Gaussian. All we needed was that each interval $(a,b) \subset \Bbb{R}$ has positive probability $\mathbb{P}(X_k \in (a,b)) >0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I feel a bit unsure about the part where we apply Borel-Cantelli. Since $\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(1\right)}\right) = \ell > 0$, dont we get $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{q,n}^{\left(k\right)}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\ell = \infty$, so that we can't apply Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: @Marc: What you wrote is true. Thus, we can apply what is called the second Borel Cantelli Lemma, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result

Comment: Ah, my bad. Thank you very much for the response. I actually had a proof where I showed that $A = \overline{A}$ almost surely, but clearly there is a mistake in there. Unfortunately it is not the result I had hoped for :'(